# Akka http outGoingConnection is stuck

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Calling the below `httpConnection` is neither returning `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]]` nor going into catch block.

It's just stuck.

```scala
lazy val httpConnection= Try{
    logger("Logger statement")
    http().outgoingConnection(host,port)
}
catch {
   case e:Exception: /***Action***/
}

httpConnection match {
  case f: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse,Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] => Source.single(request).via(flow).runWith(Sink.head)
  case e: Exception => logger("not able to get connection")
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because it's `lazy val`? It's not evaluated until accessed (https://www.baeldung.com/scala/lazy-val) . Perhaps you are wrong by saying it's stuck.

Comment: i made lazy val on-purpose. so it's not evaluated until it's required. What i mean by stuck means , it's not actually returning the flow or coming out of that try block.

Comment: And how do you know it's not returning? What do you observe to be sure it's stuck on that particular call? I suggested it's not called at all since you don't show in your snippet a reference to `httpConnection` that would actually trigger evaluation.

Comment: I can't think of why it would be stuck especially that there should be no network call happening until you hook up the `Flow` with `Source` and call `runWith` or friends on it, so I would still suspect that code is not stuck as you say.

Comment: And how do you know it's not returning? ---> my service prints the loggers present inside that try block and then it stuck . No error or nothing processed.

Comment: I can't think of why it would be stuck especially that there should be no network call happening until you hook up the Flow with Source and call runWith-- > yes, I'm doing that.   I'm checking if httpConnection has returned a Flow then it will be Source.single(request).via(flow).runWith(Sink.head)

Comment: Perhaps you could post the full example of your code cuz what's in your question doesn't have any log statements nor the Source.single part. Perhaps it's relevant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237903/discussion-between-aravinda-and-artur).

Comment: Hi Artur , i have posted with sample here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69470479/akka-http-outgoingconnection-stuck. somehow i faced too many errors while editing the current one